# Why is makefile recompiling entire set of files if I only change one?

Tags: makefile

Here is my makefile...  Why does it recompile all sources even if only one changes??

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -w -g -c
LIBS = -lm

EXEC = DFMS_PDS_L2_to_L3

.PHONY : clean tgz wdtgz

HOMEDIR = ../
BIN = bin
SRC = src
OBJ = obj

SRCFILES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cc)
OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.cc, $(OBJ)/%.o, $(notdir $(SRCFILES)))
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(notdir $(SRCFILES)))

# Executable Targets
all:    $(EXEC)

$(EXEC) : $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(LIBS) $(OBJFILES) -o $(BIN)/$(EXEC)

# Dependencies
%.o: $(SRC)/%.cc
$(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJ)/$@

# Miscellaneous Targets 
clean:
rm -rf $(BIN)/$(EXEC) obj/*.o *~

tgz:
tar cvzf $(HOMEDIR)cppbuild.tgz $(HOMEDIR)cppbuild --exclude=data
cp $(HOMEDIR)cppbuild.tgz $(HOMEDIR)cppbuild.tgz.allow

wdtgz:
tar cvzf $(HOMEDIR)cppbuild.tgz $(HOMEDIR)cppbuild
cp $(HOMEDIR)cppbuild.tgz $(HOMEDIR)cppbuild.tgz.allow
```

I'm running on Linux 3.0 with gnu make

Is it in the $(EXEC) definition?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that this recompiles all of the sources even if *none* changes.

Look at these two rules:

```
$(EXEC) : $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(LIBS) $(OBJFILES) -o $(BIN)/$(EXEC)

%.o: $(SRC)/%.cc
$(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJ)/$@
```

Suppose `foo.cc` is the only source file. The first rule says that the target depends on `foo.o`, but actually builds it from `obj/foo.o`. The second can be invoked to build `foo.o` (which the first rule demands), but it actually builds `obj/foo.o`. So the first time you run Make it will build the executable correctly (and `obj/foo.o`). But every time thereafter, Make sees that `foo.o` does not exist and attempts to build it and rebuild the executable.

The solution is to rewrite the rules so that they build -- and depend on -- what they claim:

```
all: $(BIN)/$(EXEC)

$(BIN)/$(EXEC) : $(OBJFILES)
$(CC) $(LIBS) $^ -o $@

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cc
$(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```